# How to determine what encryption was used in phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, hash, phpmyadmin

Long story short... My client web programmer is no longer among us.

He made my client's website with a custom build CMS. No one has the passwords for the admin.

But we do have access to the cPanel and DB. So I decided to get into it and create a new user, by copying the existing user. To make this work I need to encrypt the password, right? But how do I determine which type of encryption to use? I need to use the same right?

I tried MD5, but it did not work...

Heres a screenshot of the existing users hash

[image: Screenshot from phpMyAdmin]

Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: Why not look at the code for the CMS to see how it compares the passwords?

Answer (score 0):

40 hex digits means SHA-1. But there may be a salt added before the password is hashed; you'll need to read the CMS source code in order to see if this is the case.